# Multiple union statements in hive is not giving correct result

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive

I am trying to run simple transformation in Hive where multiple union and union all statements are used. I am pulling data from Oracle.
**Oracle Query:**

```
SELECT t1.column1,                      
       t2.column2,                      
       t1.column3,                                              
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2                     
  WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.column2 IN (3, 5, 8, 13) 

UNION ALL                       

  (SELECT t1.column1,                       
          t2.column2,                       
          t1.column3,                                               
    FROM table1 t1, table2 t2                       
    WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.column2 = 4    

   UNION                        

   SELECT t1.column1,                       
          t2.column2,                       
          t1.column3,                                               
     FROM table1 t1, table2 t2                          
     WHERE A.CAL = B.CAL and a.type = 4                         
           and (t1.column1 not like '%ABC%))
```

**Hive Query:**

```
SELECT t1.column1,                      
       t2.column2,                      
       t1.column3,                                              
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2                     
  WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.column2 IN (3, 5, 8, 13) 

UNION ALL                       

  SELECT sub1.*
    from (SELECT t1.column1,                        
                 t2.column2,                        
                 t1.column3,                                                
            FROM table1 t1, table2 t2                       
            WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.column2 = 4    

          UNION                     

          SELECT t1.column1,                        
                 t2.column2,                        
                 t1.column3,                                                
            FROM table1 t1, table2 t2                           
            WHERE A.CAL = B.CAL and a.type = 4                      
            and (t1.column1 not like '%ABC%)) sub1;
```

Ideally, both the queries should give me the same result, but I see count mismatch in both the queries. I do not understand where am I going wrong?

Comment: Tip of the day : whether it's hive or Oracle, use ANSI join syntax, rather than implicit joins a,b syntax.

Comment: Observing multiple syntax errors in you SQL like missing expression, quoted string not terminated properly. Please share validated/tested SQL.